# Action Bar looks old in only one activity, but the rest look ok

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I ran into a bug when I was making custom themes to use different action bar colors.

My action bar looks like this everywhere in my app except my list activity:

[image]

My list activity's action bar looks like this:

[image]

I tried looking at old commits I had saved and tried to copy their android_manifest themes and parent themes, but nothing changed. What could possibly have caused this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my problem was because I had typed in `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black);` in the activity that had the issue (the list activity). I needed to delete this, and then it worked. I forgot that you could override the theme programmatically, and that I should check my list activity for any "setTheme()" methods.

```
@Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         Log.d("SongListActivity", "onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)");
         setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black); //<----- BUG
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_songlist_list);
```